# Cannot move defined variables between stages in JenkinsFile (Scripted)

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a scriptedJenkins file:

```
node{
build_id = env.BUILD_ID
stage("Clone") {
    checkout scm
}
stage("Build"){
    def docker_image = docker.build("articlestream:${env.BUILD_ID}")
}
stage("test"){
    // we should do testing here in the future
}
stage("Docker Push"){

    //our Registry
    docker.withRegistry("https://localhost:4000", "docker-registry-credentials") {

        docker_image.push("latest")
    }
}
```

}

My expectation is that the `def docker_image` would be accessible in the `"Docker Push"` stage. However, I get the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: docker_image for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:291)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:295)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:271)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:271)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:271)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:17)
```

which suggests that docker_image is not a variable at this stage. I can confirt that docker is building an image in the build stage (checked logs) Can someone help me rephrase teh `docker_image.push("latest")` line so that I can push?

Comment: Remove the `def` keyword - `docker_image = docker.build("articlestream:${env.BUILD_ID}")`. That should propagate the variable across stages.